# Bulk importing of CSV when using header files

Tags: neo4j

Hoping someone can help me with using neo4j-import. I am trying to follow the tutorial at http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/, with a separate header file. I hope someone can help with what I assume is a simple error.

If I try to import from a CSV that has the header row, it works.

```
head patents.csv

hanID:ID|Appln|Publn_auth|Patent_number
1832552|1|EP|EP1037159

$NB/neo4j-import --into test.db --nodes "patents2.csv" --delimiter "|" --skip-duplicate-nodes
```

If I try with the header row in a separate file, it seems to run fine, but it creates 0 nodes.

```
cat header.csv

hanID:ID|Appln|Publn_auth|Patent_number

head -n 1 patents.csv

1832552|1|EP|EP1037159

$NB/neo4j-import --into test.db --nodes "header.csv, patents.csv" --delimiter "|" --skip-duplicate-nodes
```

I feel like I'm following the tutorial exactly, so I'm truly befuddled.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space after the comma in the list of files:

```
$NB/neo4j-import --into test.db --nodes "header.csv,patents.csv" --delimiter "|" --skip-duplicate-nodes
```

instead of

```
$NB/neo4j-import --into test.db --nodes "header.csv, patents.csv" --delimiter "|" --skip-duplicate-nodes
```

Note that the output did tell you that it was only importing the header:

```
Neo4j version: 3.0.7
Importing the contents of these files into test.db:
Nodes:
  /path/to/header.csv

Available resources:
...
```

With the fixed command line:

```
Neo4j version: 3.0.7
Importing the contents of these files into test.db:
Nodes:
  /path/to/header.csv
  /path/to/patents.csv

Available resources:
...
```

Yes, `neo4j-import` can be a bit too strict and literal at times. You could open an [enhancement request](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues) so it's more relaxed and trims whitespace.